# Can allies' spells be cast within Lesser Globe of Invulnerability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Can a character cast any spell on an ally within a *Globe of Invulnerability*? For example, can a cleric cast *Cure light Wounds* or *Resist Energy* on an ally while both are within the Globe?

The description says:

> The area or effect of any such spells does not include the area of the lesser globe of invulnerability. Such spells fail to affect any target located within the globe.

That seems to say that no, all spells cast on an area or target within the globe will not function, regardless of the caster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, spells can't be cast at all on targets in the area.

As long as the target is in the area and spells are lower or equal than 4th level they just don't work on the target, regardless of allies and enemies.